# How to search my list by 3 different parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, lambda, datagrid, expression

I'm using list of articles as `ItemsSource` to my `DataGrid` in WPF, beside that `DataGrid` on same Window.xaml I have one textbox where I can type some letters or numbers and filter my `DataGrid`, and right now I implemented search by:

> Article Title
>
> Article Shortcut

and now I want to implement search by article codes, one article can contain few different article codes, by now I created search by Title and Shortcut and it looks like this ( I even dont know is it good approach to do it like this way (Setting DataGrid source all the time):

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string searchParameter = txtSearch.Text.Trim();

    var matchingvalues = articleList.Where(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Title.ToLower().Contains(searchParameter.ToLower())
                                                 || stringToCheck.ArticleShortcut.ToLower().Contains(searchParameter.ToLower()));

    if (matchingvalues != null)
    {
        dtgArtikli.ItemsSource = matchingvalues;
    }
}
```

Here is my article class:

```
public class Article
{
    public Article();

    public List<ArticleCodes> ArticleCode { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Shortcut { get; set; }
}
```

So guys my question is how could I implement search by `ArticleCodes` also and not only by `Title` and `Shortcut`?

EDIT:

Table ArticleCodes database table (values that I'm searching by is "123321123321"):

[image]

Class ArticleCode:

```
 public class ArticleCode
 {

        public ArticleCode();

        public int ArticleId { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
 }
```

So lambda expression **mm8** write, should look like this:

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string searchParameter = txtSearch.Text.Trim().ToLower();
    var matchingvalues = articleList.Where(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Title.ToLower().Contains(searchParameter)
        || stringToCheck.ArticleShortcut.ToLower().Contains(searchParameter)
        || stringToCheck.ArticleCode != null && stringToCheck.ArticleCode.Any(code => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(code.Value) && code.Value.Contains(searchParameter)));

    dtgArtikli.ItemsSource = matchingvalues;
}
```

But unfortunatelly there are no results when I type "123321123321" in `txtSearch` textbox, something we missed obliviously.. hm

Thanks 
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and replace "Code" with the actual name of the property of the `ArticleCodes` class that you want to compare with:

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string searchParameter = txtSearch.Text.Trim().ToLower();
    var matchingvalues = articleList.Where(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Title.ToLower().Contains(searchParameter)
        || stringToCheck.ArticleShortcut.ToLower().Contains(searchParameter)
        || (stringToCheck.ArticleCode != null && stringToCheck.ArticleCode.Any(code => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(code.Code) && code.Code.ToLower().Contains(searchParameter))));

    dtgArtikli.ItemsSource = matchingvalues;
}
```

Comment: Mate, check for my Edit please.

Comment: Is the ArticleCode collection of the Article objects populated with any items?

Comment: You are right, I am not returning ArticlesCode form database, I remember I avoided that because of performance, in case I load 1000 articles with 10 ArticlesCode on each that would be a lot of data, so I implemented logic on dtgArticles SelectionChanged to get my selected article's codes, whatever to make this work I must make join on db to return articleCodes also on form load, and I guess this lambda expression you wrote will work as charm :) :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not to use code behind text_changed event but to go for MVVM approach and bind a CLR property with Text property of Text box and subscribe it for every change made by setting updatesourcetrigger="Propertychanged". You can write ArticalList filter logic in setter of this Property and you are done.

Let me know if you need any help in this implementation.

> XAML

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchParameter,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
         Height="30" Width="150" Margin="10">
</TextBox>
<DataGrid Name="ArticaldgGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding ArticleList}"
          Height="300" Width="300">
</DataGrid>
```

> VM

```
    private ObservableCollection<Article> articleList;

    public ObservableCollection<Article> ArticleList
    {
        get { return articleList; }
        set
        {
            articleList = value;
            //INPC method here
        }
    }

    private string searchParameter;

    public string SearchParameter
    {
        get
        {
            return searchParameter;
        }
        set
        {
            searchParameter = value;
            //Filter Logic for ArticalList ItemSource goes here
            //INPC method here
        }
    }
```

Here, whenever text in search text box gets changed, set method of SearchParameter CLR property will be called and it will intern call Filter logic that you will write.